# Xamarin Random Exception of Collection Modified

Tags: xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crash

I have created a simple navigation app in which there are multiple screens which contain Pickers, ListViews, buttons, and images using Skia sharp SVG.

Everything seems to function right but sometimes it randomly throws an exception at any random position. Even when I leave the app open for some time I get the same exception.

The error it gives is

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".

I tried to debug it. Every time it crashes and the following stack trace appeared:

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () [0x00013] in <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0 
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () [0x0004a] in <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.HandleRedrawNeeded (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.EventArg`1[T] e) [0x00022] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementTracker.cs:180 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BatchCommit () [0x0001c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions.HandleTweenerFinished (System.Object o, System.EventArgs args) [0x000cb] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\AnimationExtensions.cs:276 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Tweener.b__22_0 (System.Int64 step) [0x00095] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Tweener.cs:103 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Ticker.SendSignals (System.Int64 step) [0x0003c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\Ticker.cs:102 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Ticker.SendSignals (System.Int32 timestep) [0x00014] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\Ticker.cs:91 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidTicker.OnValOnUpdate (System.Object sender, Android.Animation.ValueAnimator+AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AndroidTicker.cs:71 
>     at Android.Animation.ValueAnimator+IAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.OnAnimationUpdate (Android.Animation.ValueAnimator animation) [0x00017] in <2960acf2eeb24d88b5230e1e8afbdc2e>:0 
>     at Android.Animation.ValueAnimator+IAnimatorUpdateListenerInvoker.n_OnAnimationUpdate_Landroid_animation_ValueAnimator_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_animation) [0x00011] in <2960acf2eeb24d88b5230e1e8afbdc2e>:0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.17(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Tools:

- Visual Studio for Mac: 8.0.3 (build 14)
- Xamarin Mac Development: 8.0.2

Testing Devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S9
- Lenovo Tab 3 7
- One Plus 5T

Comment: Looking at the stack, seems something in your animation code is causing the problem. What is your code for the Forms' Animations that are running?

Comment: The only place i m using animation is i am rotating my custom Activity indicator. Its code is as follow
Task.Run(() => RotateImageContinously(Circle1, 300));
async Task RotateImageContinously(SvgXF.Icon image, uint timeForOnChunck)
        {
            while (IsVisible) // a CancellationToken in real life ;-)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    if (image.Rotation >= 360f) image.Rotation = 0;
                    await image.RotateTo(i * (360 / 6), timeForOnChunck, Easing.Linear);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Btw Thanks for the quick reply and giving me a direction to investigate the issue (y)

Comment: @UmairBhatti Hi, Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sorry for late reply. In my case the thing fixed the issue is, i was showing a custom activity indicator view on all pages to show loading. In the cs of that view i was running 3 task to rotate 3 circles to show loading continuously with   a wait of some millisecond and was never stopping the task. 
For some odd reason when i added an implementation that when page disappears it stops the all the tasks fixed this issue at my end. 
its weird but it did work for me.

Comment: @UmairBhatti Great, you can share it in answer for others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the thing fixed the issue is, i was showing a custom activity indicator view on all pages to show loading. In the cs of that view i was running 3 task to rotate 3 circles to show loading continuously with a wait of some millisecond and was never stopping the task. For some odd reason when i added an implementation that when page disappears it stops the all the tasks fixed this issue at my end. its weird but it did work for me.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar loading animation for all my pages, almost the same code that you mentioned in the comments above, which will be executed using triggers and I have the same problem. What do you mean by 'you were never stopping the task'? When the cancellationToken is set to false, the while loop should stop running and task will be completed right? Why do we have to explicitly stop the task? Can you also show me how you stopped task from page's OnDisappearing method, it would be helpful if that really worked. Thanks in advance